# Removing URL from Omibox for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension, which I open a New Tab pointing to a custom page (domain). The problem is that I want the domain hidden in the omnibox, while still giving focus to the page. Here's what I tried so far, any other suggestions?

I tried using the "chrome_url_overrides" to create a new tab with an iframe to load my resources from my custom page/domain, this works but gives focus to the omnibox and not the iframe.

I also tried to use the Browser's History API to clear the domain, but I've only been able to remove the parameters, apparently the browser doesn't allow the domain part to be cleared.

Comment: Omnibox is always focused when opening a new tab, isn't it? This is by design, AFAICT. Anyway, there are no solutions to this other than those you mentioned. Well, except for writing a separate external utility that would focus the content area when a new tab is opened.

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have a search box on my page, and want it to always have focus. I also want the omnibox to be blank because it will display the default Chrome Search placeholder, providing for a cleaner and better search experience for the user.